# Scrapy edit the edit the link extracted from Rule

Tags: python, scrapy

I am testing on amazon to parse products, I want to scrape the products,I got the xpath for products correct,but I want to edit it to match `"https://www.amazon.com/dp/{}".format("ASIN")` i.e removing some extra stuff from link, I also got the regex for it but scrapy is showing an error when I use `process_value` from [Link Extractors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html). How can I fix this?

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from myamazon.items import MyamazonItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
import re
class AmazonSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'amazon'
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.com']
    start_urls = ['http://amazon.com/']


    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="a-last"]/a/@href')),
            Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[@class="a-link-normal a-text-normal"]'),callback="parse",
                process_value= lambda i:f"https://www.amazon.com/dp/{re.search('dp/(.*)/',i).groups()[0]}")
        )
```

the error:

```
    process_value= lambda i:re.serach('dp/(.*)/',i).groups()[0])
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'process_value'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to use parameter `process_value` in `Rule()` instead of `LinkExtractor()`.

Let's format your code:

```
rules = (
    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="a-last"]/a/@href'
        )
    ),
    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(
                restrict_xpaths='//a[@class="a-link-normal a-text-normal"]'
        ),
        callback="parse",
        process_value= lambda if: "https://www.amazon.com/dp/{re.search('dp/(.*)/',i).groups()[0]}"
     )
)
```

Here it's more obvious that `process_value` is used into `Rule()`. [scrapy.spiders.Rule](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule) does not expect `process_value`, but [LinkExtractor](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html?highlight=LinkExtractor#scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor) does.

Comment: this works, now I have a follow up question. my main idea to parse listing pages then their products this keeps following products found in products is there a way to fix this?